# How to filter filter_horizontal in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm looking for a way to use filter_horizontal on the base of a filtered queryset.

I've tried to use it with a custom manager:

**In models.py:**

```
class AvailEquipManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(AvailEquipManager, self).get_query_set().filter(id=3)

class Equipment(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    [...]
    objects = models.Manager()
    avail = AvailEquipManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.description)
```

**In admin.py:**

```
class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('equipment',) # this works but obviously shows all entries
    #filter_horizontal = ('avail',)     # this does not work
```

So the questions is, how can I reduce the left side of the filter_horizontal to show only specific items?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834540/django-filter-horizontal-filtering/39835254#39835254](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834540/django-filter-horizontal-filtering/39835254#39835254)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a solution by adapting the answer to a different question which I found in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/-46GAa0FMlc)

It works with a custom ModelForm like so:

Create a new forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from models import Equipment

class EquipmentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['equipment'].queryset = Equipment.avail.all()
```

Then in admin.py:

```
class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EquipmentModelForm
    filter_horizontal = ('equipment',)
```

Hope this helps someone else out sometime.

Comment: This is especially helpful if you need access to the model instance (with the forms `self.instance`). If you need access to the request (e.g. for the session user) you might prefer overriding `formfield_for_manytomany` in the admin as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834540/django-filter-horizontal-filtering/39835254#39835254)

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but anyway:

Depending on your specific requirements, it may be easier to set the `limit_choices_to` attribute on the `equipment` relation field. This works on `ForeignKey` fields as well as on `ManyToManyField`s.

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to), this attribute

> Sets a limit to the available choices for this field when this field
>   is rendered using a `ModelForm` or the admin ...

A minimal example, assuming you have a `System` model with `equipment` many-to-many field:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class System(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ManyToManyField(to=Equipment,
                                       limit_choices_to={'available': True})


class SystemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['equipment']
```

This uses an `available` flag, but more complex queries can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

The `formfield_for_foreignkey` method on a ModelAdmin handles this:
[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

example using `System` and foreign key to `Equipment`:

> ```
> def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
>     if db_field.name == 'equipment':
>         system = System.objects.get(id=request.resolver_match.args[0])
>         kwargs["queryset"] = system.equipment_set.all()
>     return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: Or alternatively `formfield_for_manytomany()`