# Django: Is there a way to manually order objects in a ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Photo(models.Model):
  file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

class Album(models.Model):
  photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo,related_name="photos",blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
from .models import Photo, Album

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("photos",)

admin.site.register(Photo)
admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

Is there some way to manually order the models in the filter_horizontal, or do I just have to do all that in the views.py using python?

Comment: Is this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835254/10534470) what you want ?

Comment: @EshaanBansal I believe not. I'm trying to manually order the chosen ones (on the right side).

Answer (score 0):

The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835254/10534470) adapted for your case.

```py
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("photos",)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "photos":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Photo.objects.order_by("-id") # or however u wish to order
        return super(AlbumAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I got an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347132/how-do-i-reorder-a-list-of-objects-manually-using-django-python-and-possibly