# How do I reorder a list of objects manually using Django, Python, (and possibly Javascript)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here is my code.
models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Photo(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images')

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo,related_name="photos",blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Photo, Album
# Register your models here.

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title","published")
    filter_horizontal = ("photos",)
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "photos":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Photo.objects.order_by("-id")
        return super(AlbumAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        
admin.site.register(Photo)
admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings

from .models import Photo, Album

# Create your views here.

def album(request, album_title):
    album = Album.objects.get(title=album_title)
    context = {
        "album":album,
    }
    return render(request, "photos/album.html", context)
```

I am trying to achieve a page that shows the photos in each album and has a drag-and-drop function that allows a manual re-ordering of the photos in each album. Then I wish to save the order of the album. The only problem is, I have no clue to how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a trivial task, so you can't just expect a one line answer, but I guess it's a good use case to have a look at some packages that try to solve this.

Here is a good overview of all packages that try to solve ordering, maybe one of them fits you well:
https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-ordering/

Comment: Thanks. I used django-admin-sortable2