# How can I make the multi-select function in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am using the ManyToManyField in Django models and would like to change the interphase to something better rather than the default interphase.

This is the default interphase, how can I make it like a multiple select items.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use below option under ModelAdmin inherited class which transforms widget as in image below

```
filter_horizontal = ('students', 'teacher',)
```

also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968631/how-to-filter-filter-horizontal-in-django-admin)

[image: here]

Comment: i don't think this seems like something I meant.

Comment: Widget used, is for doing multiple selects with search option.